# Display a table under each expandable row using sap ui table (Grid)

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am trying to add a sap m table under each row of sap ui table when it is expanded.

Technically as per fiori guidelines it is recommended to opt for a popover or a dialog to display the any additional data or master detail approach.

But the ask is to let user see all the child tables under each row when expand all is clicked.

[Referred SAP blog for this use case](https://blogs.sap.com/2019/04/02/sap-ui5-table-row-shift-expand/)

Unfortunately by using M table as parent is causing wrapping issues. So it has to be UI table where user can scroll from left to right if there are more columns and view the child table when expanded.

How can we achieve this functionality by not using a tree table or a m table as parent table ?